# Combine two string records in WHERE cause

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two columns **name** and **surname**. I would like to make a search query which will find the person if the user writes either name, surname or *both.*

Currently I have

```
    SELECT name, surname, id FROM users WHERE 
    (name LIKE '%".$term."%' || surname LIKE
    '%".$term."%')  AND position='0' LIMIT 5
```

Let's say I have a user John Lemon. The query will find him if I write *John* or I write *Lemon*. 
But it will find nothing if I write *John Lemon*.

Is it possible to have a syntax similar to:

```
 SELECT name, surname, id FROM users WHERE (
  name+' '+surname LIKE
 '%".$term."%')  AND position='0' LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Note that it's good practice to use `OR` instead of `||` in SQL (and likewise with `AND` instead of `&&`). MySQL lets you get away with it, but other SQL engines don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT name, surname, id FROM users WHERE
CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) LIKE '%".$term."%'
```

Comment: so why to write more conditions like urs :P:D

Comment: Well done, VIPIN JAIN. CONCAT was the one I was looking for. And it seems I don't need two previous (name and surname) causes.

Comment: But `name` is "John", which is not `LIKE '%John Lemon%'`

Comment: lol if john is searched it will be searched because of those `%` signs

Comment: `name`: John -- `surname`: Lemon -- `$term`: John Lemon -- `SELECT name,surname FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%John Lemon%' OR surname LIKE '%John Lemon%'` will not find John Lemon's record. Your query would find John Lemon with a $term of `Jo` or `Lem` though.

Comment: @Andrew Leach hey first check the answer before commenting

Comment: The question specifies you need to find John Lemon's record with a search term of `John Lemon` where `name` and `surname` contain substrings of the search term. `John` (in the `name` field) is not `LIKE '%John Lemon%'`, and will not be found. I've just tested that to make sure, too.

Comment: Of course, if you change your answer in the edit time so it's not flagged, then anything goes, I suppose.

Comment: Andrew, yes, that was the problem. And that's why in this case CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) helps as it joins name and surname. And it will be find it whether I search for "hn Lem" or "John" or "John Lemon"

Comment: lol the one you r thinking is the arturs one check his answer :P:D

Comment: Note, this more than likely won't make use of any indexes you might have on your name columns, and instead will probably resort to a table scan.  This would cause a pretty big performance hit if you have lots of people's names in your table.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
SELECT name, surname, id FROM users WHERE
    name LIKE '%".$term."%'
    OR surname LIKE '%".$term."%'
    OR CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) LIKE '%".$term."%'
```

Comment: Ace! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: VIPIN JAIN's solution is better, use his.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is MySQL's [concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

```
WHERE CONCAT(NAME,' ',SURNAME) LIKE '%".$term."%'
```